# Sequelize warning: `resolve/lib/core` is deprecated; please use `is-core-module` directly

Tags: javascript, module, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

While using sequelize-cli

```
"db-migrate": "node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate"
```

i got a warning:

```
`resolve/lib/core` is deprecated; please use `is-core-module` directly
```

Any suggestions how to use properly

Comment: Try to remove node_modules and install packages once again. It helped me